# Android development: need suggestions for writing server-client sides app

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I'm working on an app that should communicate and transfer data between different devices.
For example, sending messages, comparing data vars, etc.
I have a bit of experience with JAVA PLAY framework, which use a java server side with routing and MVC, and HTTP with JS on the client side.

I dont know where to begin. I have been going through the internet for hours trying to find some info on how to implement this server client model.
I saw few examples about send messages with serversocket, but none was explained enough.
I would really appreciate any guide or explanation on this subject.

Thanks! Itai.

Comment: Are you looking to communicate from a mobile device to a web server?  Is that your intent?

Comment: No. Sorry if I wasnt clear. I want to write an app, that can communicate with different android devices, i.e, using a server.
For example, whatsapp, fun run...
I just dont know how to do it, since I dont have any experience with this server client based apps, so I guess I have to study the basics first. I just cant find where to learn that from.